# Kendo UI Hierarchical grid shows no header for child elements

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have an ASP.NET MVC application.
Here is my view code.
The problem that I am facing is that the kendo UI hierarchical grid does no show headers for child elements. Can you provide me any hint?

Here is the grid in the index file:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script id="expandTemplate" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Portal.Web.Areas.Orders.Models.RegistroDetail>()
            .Name("grid")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(r => r.CodiceMateriale).Title("Codice Materiale");
                columns.Bound(r => r.TestoBreve).Title("Testo Breve");
                columns.Bound(r => r.MagazzinoLogicoPrecedente).Title("Magazzino logico precedente");
                columns.Bound(r => r.Quantità).Title("Quantità");
                columns.Bound(r => r.Resi).Title("Resi");

            })
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(10)
                .Read(read => read.Action("RegistroDetail_Read", "RegistroRicondizionamento"))
            )
            .Pageable()
            .Scrollable()
            .ToClientTemplate()
        )
    </script>
}

<div class="position-detail-container">
    <div class="table-container">
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Portal.Web.Areas.Orders.Models.Registroheader>()
            .Name("grid")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(r => r.CodiceMateriale).Title("Codice Materiale");
                columns.Bound(r => r.TestoBreve).Title("Testo Breve");
                columns.Bound(r => r.UM).Title("UM");
                columns.Bound(r => r.Quantità).Title("Quantità");

            })
            .Scrollable()
            .ClientDetailTemplateId("expandTemplate")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "", id = "grid" })
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Read(read => read.Action("RegistroHeader_Read", "RegistroRicondizionamento", Model))
             )
            .Deferred()
        )
    </div>

    <script>
    function dataBound() {
        this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
    }
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Is is showing data, but no headers? Any console errors?

Comment: no console errors